# What is the space complexity of a recursive fibonacci algorithm without considering stack calls?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

If we don't consider stack call memory, then what is the space consumed by the recursive fibnonacci?

I read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756045/what-is-the-space-complexity-of-a-recursive-fibonacci-algorithm) and it says 0(N) but I am confused whether we should include stack memory or not while considering the space.

The pseudocode:

```
int Fibonacci(int n)
{
   if ( n == 0 )
      return 0;
   else if ( n == 1 )
      return 1;
   else
      return ( Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2) );
}
```

Comment: Which recursive Fibonacci algorithm? There are at least two that I know of, likely there are more.

Comment: https://forgetcode.com/c/188-fibonacci-series-using-recursion

Comment: You should include this in the question. Even as a pseudo code.

Comment: If you consider stack-memory depends on you. I would say of cause memory used on a stack is also used memory, so why shouldn't i be counted.

Comment: All allocation in the snippet you link to is on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

without considering stack call memory, It is again O(n) because you are passing a variable whose copy gets created in new function call, and this happens n times in n functions as maximum height of the recursion tree at any time is n or maximum level is n + 1 so asymptotically we can say it is O(n).

In case of bottom up approach again we use array to store the past value so that also becomes O(n) space(but in a clever way, we can make bottom up approach to work with only 3 variables which can be considered as O(1) space).